# docker-compose volume empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose config file:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  devbox:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: DevBox.DockerFile
    volumes:
      - "./html:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    
  devmysql:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: MySQLDev.DockerFile
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'secret'
    restart: always
    volumes:
            - "./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.0.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: dev-mysql
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
volumes:
  mysql-data: {}
  html: {}
```

The problem is that the volume on the devbox is empty even if the html dir is not.

If I run:

```
docker run -d -v ./html:/usr/src/app testdocker_devbox
```

It works as expected.

I don't see problem in my config file.

My DevBox.Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 
RUN apt-get install -y php 
RUN apt-get install -y php-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y php-mysql 
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php 
RUN apt-get install -y php-curl 
RUN apt-get install -y php-json 
RUN apt-get install -y php-common 
RUN apt-get install -y php-mbstring 
RUN apt-get install -y composer
RUN curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | /bin/bash
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
#RUN apt-get install -y php 7.2-phalcon
# COPY ./php.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
# COPY ./slc.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/slc.conf
# COPY ./apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
# RUN rm -rfv /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf
# RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/slc.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/slc.conf

CMD ["apachectl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
RUN a2enmod rewrite
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Comment: Are you running the docker-compose command from the same directory you ran the "docker run" command?

Comment: I was able to verify that this should work with this config: 

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  devbox:
    image: alpine:latest
    volumes:
      - "./html:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Is there something else that's different?

Comment: Can you post the docker file for devbox?

Comment: @Carlos added the DevBox Dockerfile

Comment: @Carlos yes I'm running the commands from the same path

Comment: I suggest you to use full path : /path/to/html:/usr/src/app

Comment: Does your mysql volume mount correctly or are you having the same issue?

Comment: It could be something related to permissions on the local folder.  I have not been able to reproduce the issue using standard images like nginx or even when using your exact Dockerfile.

Comment: Could you show how you run docker-compose? And how do you check container emptiness? (asking because i didn't reproduce your issue with your docker files)

Comment: `docker inspect [devbox-container-name]` will help you findout full path that container is mounting. checkout `Mounts` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the application being on /tmp of my Mac. If I use a non /tmp path it works. This should be due to the fact that /tmp is a link to /private/tmp/

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the volumes declaration at this end of your docker-compose.yml. This is used for named volume not for volumes mapped with host directory [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

```
# remove this part then it should be fine
volumes:
  mysql-data: {}
  html: {}
```

Comment: I already tried that. Actually that two lines were added later just to check if in this way the volumes were mounted

Answer (score 0):

Change local path `./html`  in

```
volumes:
  - "./html:/usr/src/app"
```

to absolute path